# How come constexpr functions can not consume consteval functions while you can create constexpr objects from consteval functions?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, consteval

You can have constexpr objects fron consteval
but you can not consume consteval within constexpr.

Why?

I thought consteval should have been some kind of "narrow" constexpr.

Please help me make a sense out of this design.

```
constexpr int constexpr_sqr(int n) { return n*n; }
consteval int consteval_sqr(int n) { return n*n; }
constexpr int constexpr_sqr2(int n) { 
  // not allowed
  // return consteval_sqr(n);
   
  // not allowed
  // constexpr imm = consteval_sqr(n);
  // return imm;

  return constexpr_sqr(n);
}
int main() {
  // while can do this
  constexpr auto imm = consteval_sqr(999);
}
```

[[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIRmzyAZ2ydURAg2rZ6mAMLp2AVwC29HgHZyOzABkC9bADlTAI2ykQVgA7olxTXoDYzNLcl9/DQZ7RxcTd08rFTUo%2BiYiVlIiYNNzbiTVbHVA9MyiGOc3Dy9lDKyc0Pzasoq4hK8ASmV0I1JULgByDHolImwAD29SAGoHImnh0YmpgH0lAEdSCDnp%2Bg7pyQtZadJsIl76XYAqekkAZmPDgBFJAAYAQUWxgDcOWcYFgwlr92GtNtsAXsDkcTmcLtdbg9oS8Pl9ljMdmjJqQwaRpBD5lDDo8PtNpgB6cm7dDzDjsdAAd2wmDe7zJlNh51IlzRINxED293kpLJrPZVPoNOmdMZzLFFKpWKmsxMJgOdyegJGPw4/MFD3lHNOXMuBFVQtZ8uN8KVOI2W31wvez1ZOxMrAcEH2xPltulRhIKrV901vN19ogAE5ox0LR8XR8Bl12CABgBWAbkcwDV6Z9CpvQKBTTJQ9PrYA7SO7cTNEVO5jpdADWIAAbK8AHS8SPVtNpyPSXjcaQADgsaZEqd4mZMIDHHdbfYs3Ej3DuA8jFhH/GzufI%2BYGmaUIFe5DrOaT5DgsBQPSI3gDlGoGBM3gInE83GshBIn/IdEYFgOC4PhyAZUhWG8VMa2TVMMyzes81TGRq2mBliCQaZxhHVsAFpW14BZRHEaYICIUgjHoJsOlrRDG3IJBsFYHBPC9ScBmnchZ2HDs7l4XhR1eHDXgsV5pG4CddyQw9lBPM86ObEA%2Bw7aQ014O5x24Rdx1baN2LuTMpP3VNaIvLprwQeAIBQF83w/J8IFs99qlQYjgBWcjKKbf93zGUhjwgVxEPIVwHEyABPaDMxfEwdCIAB5eh2Eii9yBwd1xE4YLCFOYpvmwY9UomIoA0GGtKEYVRgvYAhXAg0hwoMHBgvIs0oq6ADmDYLLQKEL83LQIs5BEWrj0gLp0G8VJCtw0YWQ1YB6CMIbZGkVhplw%2BLyuSIpUm0XQGjyaxdFaKo/wiAIGEO4QLtSU74mqL8duKBhSnqQxcmEZ7Uje8oHEqB6/1GMprqeuo/tiM6eC6Uten6aH2PgoyD2wvCCKIsRgFIzyqP2CB8GIMhK2rchpgMV9nJmFDuH2Qs5AUUyG0U/iOwsXg01bQcRz4wc7leO52M42c01PZGTNk09zwbK9EGskBitQAMyAczJgCUAAFMRVCYJBGWzcqnNEVJNccdgdb14LDZctyPIoqjyCt0h4oDc2GSMhX3lINXxYV9JCGzTNOqAnr%2BCEaQRExwb6eGmrXDGtjJum1NZqIeankW5bo9W14Nq2o8y3hsH/ZN7XdbdujEcM4KUZw/DCNczHsbt6jplwcYSt/UiCc76naZWxmky6RjmOqNiUw4mclNF6vxePSWFPIFsWbZjmuZ59T%2Bf0qvUoPAf6PH6RJ%2B4V5p538WpcH8h8v8wIQF4IA%3D)]

Comment: Because function argument are never constant expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the argument. `constexpr` function aren't required to be constant evaluated. This means that `n` is not usable in a constant expression.

> I thought consteval should have been some kind of "narrow" constexpr.

No, those are just functions that *have* to be constant evaluated. This means that their arguments must *always* be usable in a constant expressions.

You can call a `constexpr` function with arguments that are not usable in a constant expression, and so long as you aren't in a context that requires a constant expression, it's still well-formed.

Comment: Ah... consteval simply collapses the "superposition" of constexpr function.